# ¿Cómo se ajusta la escala logarítmica en un gráfico de dispersión (plot.scatter)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Requiero presentar un gráfico de dispersión en escala logarítmica de los siguientes array:

```
x =[1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17,
   18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34,
   35, 36, 37, 39, 42, 44, 48]

y = [2.43310035e-01, 1.98717530e-01, 1.49977138e-01, 1.14921506e-01,
   8.24242820e-02, 5.90611187e-02, 4.29377055e-02, 3.07771028e-02,
   2.14144185e-02, 1.56552790e-02, 1.08977290e-02, 8.31754741e-03,
   5.73736582e-03, 3.95192371e-03, 2.91767370e-03, 2.46042633e-03,
   1.77455527e-03, 1.16489211e-03, 7.94739478e-04, 7.51192109e-04,
   5.22568424e-04, 2.61284212e-04, 2.39510528e-04, 1.41528948e-04,
   1.74189475e-04, 1.30642106e-04, 1.41528948e-04, 1.19755264e-04,
   6.53210530e-05, 3.26605265e-05, 2.17736843e-05, 2.17736843e-05,
   7.62078951e-05, 2.17736843e-05, 2.17736843e-05, 0.00000000e+00,
   0.00000000e+00, 2.17736843e-05, 2.17736843e-05, 0.00000000e+00,
   0.00000000e+00]
```

Inicialmente hago el `plot.scatter` usando la siguiente instrucción:

```
plt.scatter(x,y)
```

La imagen que obtengo es esta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero usar escala logarítmica en el eje Y, pero si uso la instrucción `plt.yscale('log')` no me salen todos los puntos de la gráfica, solo me salen 4 puntos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguien me puede ayudar? ¿Qué debo hacer para que me muestre todos los datos, usando escala logarítmica en el eje Y?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`scatter` aparentemente tiene problemas para autoescalar automáticamente la grafica cuando hay valores muy pequeños ([reporte del problema en GitHub](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/6015)). Tienes varias alternativas:

Puedes usar [`matplotlib.pyplot.semilogy`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.semilogy.html) en lugar de `scatter`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x =[1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17,
   18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34,
   35, 36, 37, 39, 42, 44, 48]
y = [2.43310035e-01, 1.98717530e-01, 1.49977138e-01, 1.14921506e-01,
   8.24242820e-02, 5.90611187e-02, 4.29377055e-02, 3.07771028e-02,
   2.14144185e-02, 1.56552790e-02, 1.08977290e-02, 8.31754741e-03,
   5.73736582e-03, 3.95192371e-03, 2.91767370e-03, 2.46042633e-03,
   1.77455527e-03, 1.16489211e-03, 7.94739478e-04, 7.51192109e-04,
   5.22568424e-04, 2.61284212e-04, 2.39510528e-04, 1.41528948e-04,
   1.74189475e-04, 1.30642106e-04, 1.41528948e-04, 1.19755264e-04,
   6.53210530e-05, 3.26605265e-05, 2.17736843e-05, 2.17736843e-05,
   7.62078951e-05, 2.17736843e-05, 2.17736843e-05, 0.00000000e+00,
   0.00000000e+00, 2.17736843e-05, 2.17736843e-05, 0.00000000e+00,
   0.00000000e+00]


plt.semilogy(x, y, marker='o', ls="") 
plt.show()
```

Otra opción es usar `matplotlib.pyplot.plot`:

```
plt.plot(x, y, marker = "o", ls="")
plt.yscale('log')
plt.show()
```

Si por lo que sea quieres usar `matplotlib.pyplot.scatter`, puedes especificar manualmente los límites del eje `y`:

```
plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.yscale('log')
plt.ylim(10**-5, 1)
plt.show()
```

En todos los casos obtenemos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias por su respuesta, el único problema que tengo es que necesito que los puntos no se conecten con línea, si aplico el `semilogy` se me conectan los puntos, esto se puede cambiar?

Comment: @Karla eso no es problema, se me pasó por alto, eso se consigue con el parámetro `ls=""`, editada. He añadido otras opciones además.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!!!!